# Updating a subset of apps in a marathon group

Tags: marathon

When using the `v2/groups` API to update a subset of applications in a group, how does one specify the configuration for those apps that are unchanged? Does the update request have to include the full original configuration for the unchanged app, or does one simply have to include its `id` to indicate it is still part of the group but with configuration unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

- use `PUT` on the group and include the unchanged configuration as well. Marathon will detect which apps are changed and only redeploy changed applications.
- use `PUT` on the app endpoint to only change one of the apps in isolation.